# AngularJs: resolving a promise doesn't update my scope

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I am under the impression that binding to a promise in my html

```
<ul ng-repeat='i in items'>
    <li>{{i}}</li>
</ul>
```

(where `$scope.items` is the promise), that when the promise is resolved, the scope will automatically update.

```
var _deferred = $q.defer();

$scope.items = _deferred.promise;

$scope.setItems = function() {
  _deferred.resolve([
    'Here',
    'There',
    'Everywhere'
  ]);
};
```

When I call `setItems()`, the promise is resolved, but my html doesn't update.

What am I doing wrong?

[Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/xaNNBMQnjh2z7y8BKQHi?p=preview)

Comment: Using Angular UI Router you can resolve promises: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you are setting items is not correct. `$scope.items` should not be a Promise object, but you should use Promise `then` methods to set items:

```
_deferred.promise.then(function(items) {
    $scope.items = items;
});
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/4dtyniFayCHKrD1exWV1?p=preview

Comment: @SteveLorimer Well actually in earlier versions of Angular you could assign promise to scope properties directly like you were trying to do it. But you can't any more. And this is good, setting scope items explicitly makes code more readable.